# chrome detect when computer wakes up from idle state

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm making a Chrome extension that receives Chrome Google Cloud Messages. I want to detect when computer wakes up from sleep/reconnects to internet, so that my application can start receiving messages again. For my specific case, I don't want GCM to throttle the pushes, so I set the ttl to 0, which is deliver now or never. (user device will never receive message while idle.)

In javascript, how do I detect when Chrome browser recovers from idle state?

More specifically, how could I do it in Chrome extension using chrome. api calls?

Comment: I wonder if you really need to do so. I would expect that Google manages receiving GCM for you after you've called `register` once.

Comment: So you want to communicate this fact to your GCM server? Using GCM?

Comment: @Xan I will just do a manual fetch from my server on missed notifications.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Chrome has an idle API:

```
chrome.idle.onStateChanged(function(state) {
    if (state == 'active') {
        console.log('State is now active');
    }
});
```

You can read about it here:  https://developer.chrome.com/apps/idle

Comment: nice! didn't know about this.

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't tell you that the computer has woken from sleep. `onStateChanged` may fire in that case, but it also fires when the user walks away and then comes back and starts interacting with the computer, or locks and unlocks it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use idle.queryState also and put a check if state === active inside query

```
    chrome.idle.queryState(15, function (state) {
if (state === "active"){
//Your logic
}
}
```